# Select decides which form action to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

I have a form that starts with a select. Based on the choice of that first select (which report is chosen) I need to change the action path of which .cfm the form submits to. Will someone please assist me in how I should do this? I am open to any proper way whether is HTML, ColdFusion or jQuery (Javascript).

So starts with a select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
                <option id ="checklistreports" value="checklistreports" >Checklist Stats</option>
                <option id ="locationreports" value="locationreports" >Location Stats</option>
            </select>
```

If `#checklistreports` is chosen the form should be 
`<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_checklists_queries.cfm">`

But if `#locationreports` is chosen the form should be 
`<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I was trying to do in IF statement in CF but it has me stuck unfortunately with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.change` handler to change the `action` attribute of the form.

```
$("#reporttype").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "checklistreports") {
        $("form[name=generatereport]").attr("action", "_checklists_queries.cfm");
    } else {
        $("form[name=generaterport]").attr("action", "_location_queries.cfm");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have another select that asks print pdf or excel. Would this be the same spot I try to create that as well?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to just indicate the action values of the form in the values of the options.

```js
$('#reporttype').change(function(){
  form_action = $(this).val();
  $('form').attr('action', form_action);
  $('span').text(form_action);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
        <option value="_checklists_queries.cfm" >Checklist Stats</option>
        <option value="_location_queries.cfm" >Location Stats</option>
    </select>
    
<form name="generatereport" method="POST" action="#">
  <p>This forms action value is <span>#</span></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a good solution if this dropdown is only one place in the entire app that cares about the selected report. But if there are other parts of the app that care that this dropdown has selected one report over the other, then this solution is not scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it all with ColdFusion.  It's so much simpler.  Here is one approach.

```
formPage
<form action = "action.cfm" method="post">
<select name="pageToInclude">
<option value="locationQueries.cfm">Location</option>
rest of form.

action.cfm
<cfinclude template = "#form.pageToInclude#">
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an accepted answer, but I would like to propose a slightly cleaner solution to the answer you selected, as well as an alternative:

**Option #1 (Inline and Clean):**

```
// Cache the selector for better reuse.
var form = $("form[name=generatereport]");

$("#reporttype").change(function() {
    var action = $(this).val() === 'checklistreports' ? '_checklists_queries.cfm' : '_location_queries.cfm';
    form.attr('action', action);
});
```

The above option is just a more compact version of the answer you selected, but utilizes selector caching, which is good for performance.

**Option #2 ('Global' Config Options):**

```
// Cache the selector
var form = $('form[name=generatereport]');

// Now you can define the variable states for your app.
var config = {
    checklistreports: {
      action: '_checklists_queries.cfm'
    },
    locationreports: {
      action: '_location_queries.cfm'
    }
};

// Updating is trivial
$('#reporttype').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    form.attr('action', config[selected].action);
});
```

This option is interesting because it lets you define all the different "states" for your components in one place, which is nice for readability and maintenance, and it makes the actual updating of components as simple as looking up the values it should have.

Answer (score 0):

If the forms contains differents elements, you could hide the forms with css and with an onchange handler on the select unhide the right form.

html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
  <option value="checklistreports" >Checklist Stats</option>
  <option value="locationreports" >Location Stats</option>
</select>

<form method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm" id="locationreports" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="location">
</form>
<form method="post" action="_checklists_queries.cfm" id="checklistreports" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="checklist">
</form>
```

js:

```
var locationReport = document.getElementById("locationreports");
var checklistReport = document.getElementById("checklistreports");

function onChangeForm(e) {
  if (e.target.value === "locationreports") {
    locationReport.style.display = "block";
    checklistReport.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    checklistReport.style.display = "block";
    locationReport.style.display = "none";
  }
}
document.getElementById("reporttype").onchange = onChangeForm;
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ts5789s8/3/)